# ¿Cómo puedo generar registros en una coleccion de MongoDB automaticamente?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, backend, colecciones

estoy desarrollando una aplicación full stack, por primera vez ya que siempre me dedique al Front.
Una de las funcionalidades que me piden es que un usuario Admin, genere una lista de tareas para que otros usuarios las cumplan, estas tareas deben ejecutarse con una determinada frecuencia, pueden ser diarias, es decir, la misma tarea todos los dias, semanales, quincenales o mensuales, en este ultimo caso, la tarea se va a ejecutar una vez por mes...
Una tarea puede ser por ejemplo: Limpiar filtros, frecuencia: Diaria, encargado: Jose, Cumplido: False.
La idea es que el usuario Jose, al loguearse vea todas las tareas que tiene que hacer y a medida que las va cumpliendo lo deje plasmado en la aplicacion, pero por ejemplo si es una tarea diaria, hoy la cumplio, pero mañana la tendra que ver nuevamente.
El asunto es como puedo desde el back automatizar la generación de registros en la coleccion, para que si la tarea es diaria, tenga 5 documentos por semana (De L a V) de tareas a cumplir?
He leido que acerca de Node-Cron, pero no estoy seguro si puedo aplicarlo en esta funcionalidad.
Como dato extra, estoy usando Express, MongoDB y mongoose y en el front tengo pensado usar React.
Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida!

Comment: O también podrías solo guardar la definición de la tarea y cuando cada usuario la marcó como cumplida... y luego basado en esos 2 datos sabes cuales hizo y cuales tiene por hacer... (asi no te enredas con andar creando nuevos registros automaticamente), porque (sin conocer tu sistema), si por ejemplo tienes 1000 usuarios, a los cuales les pones una tarea diaria, y supongamos que solo 2 de ellos la cumplen, en una semana tendrías 7000 (14 marcados como "realizados").... si guardas la definicion, tendrías un registro para definirla y 14 registros de marcado completa.

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Las preguntas muy amplias y/o basadas en opiniones terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions).